# Can i put a logic in different file to process a fragment file? Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

so i have a project that consist of tabbed activity which contains listViews on each tab

tab 1 - for browsing title
tab 2 - for browsing which title that users clicked

and i put the onCreateView method of each fragment separately.

```js
public class ChatHistory extends Fragment {
    private ListView mThreadList;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_history, container, false);

    }
}
```

on each tab i want to add method to call data from firebase to a list view in each fragment.

what i want to know is, where should i put my logic of each fragment so that it can process the data input output ? and how do i put it.

thanks for the help.

Comment: please post logic here , so people have idea what you want to call again and again ...

Comment: before return view inside onCreateView() ,you can call your WS using any user define method  and process your data set your list etc. and thats it..

Comment: @Radhey i tried to define a method but it wont let me to define my ListView variable, i was trying to define mListView = (ListView) findViewByID. sorry but i am new at android

Comment: follow @Napstars answer ,its little bit complex but gives you centralized method for all your fragments that extends BaseFragment costume class.or else follow -Handi 's answer ,its simple and you have to manually put all the stuff as they depicted in answer for each and every fragment you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragment`s has similar lifecycle flow with `Activity`-ies. With that in mind, the best place to put initialization logics is within these methods:

- `onCreate()`
- `onCreateView()`

Now, one would argue `onCreateView()` is preferable since most of the time initialization logics in an Android application revolves around UI components. While (unlike `Activity`-ies) in `onCreate()` you're not guaranteed any access to them.

Starting from here, you can modify your `onCreateView()` a bit so it'd look like this:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_history, container, false);

        // Step 1: Initialize your views (do those nasty findViewById's here).
        mThreadList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id);

        // Step 2: Do your logic of loading the required data here.
        // …

        return view;
    }
```

But remember not to overly burden the UI thread when doing `Step 2`. Otherwise you risk triggering ANR dialogs.

---

***p.s.***, My answer may seem too broad but that is because your question currently is. If you could try to narrow down your question, I might be able to provide a better answer. :)

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer, so basically i have a project with Tab Activity and when the App is executed the Tab Activity will process which fragment that shows based on which tab that active. i have each class and extends to each fragment (Tab1 and Tab2) separetely. my question is can i add a class that extends AppCompactivity inside Tab1.class that extends fragment?

Comment: What is your end goal exactly? Do you want to access your `TabActivity` from within your fragments? Or are you wanting to reduce duplicate code? Or is it something entirely apart from those two?

Comment: my goal is i want to add Logic to both fragments inside their own class(Tab1.class and Tab2.class), so the logic wont be seperate from the Class that extends to Fragment. sorry if i describe it poorly.

Answer (score 0):

> If all your fragment are retrieving data from firebase. It's better to create a baseFragment and put all your logic their and call it from whichever fragment you want.

So it use the s**amelayout , Same design and same mThreadList in each fragment.**

```
    public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment{
    public abstract List<YourModelClass> methodToFetchDataFromFireBase(Param 1,Param 2..)//whatever your params are
    private ListView mThreadList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_history, container, false);
   }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         List<YourModelClass> anyList = methodToFetchDataFromFireBase();
         mThreadList.setAdapter(getActivity,anyList );
    }
```

Now for each fragment simply `extends` them to `BaseFragment` . No need of using `onCreateView` method. Simply add `onViewCreated` and call you method